# How to build a FSharp program on Linux just on console?

Tags: build, f#

Is it possible to build a F# program on Linux without IDE, just on console?

Comment: All languages running in the new `dotnet` runtime are cross-platform :)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, essentially create, build and run an app using the `dotnet` CLI: `dotnet new console -lang F#`, `dotnet build` and `dotnet run`

More details are in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-command-line)